# Is there an option to return after occuring error to the outest loop by try-except?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, try-except

I have the task to measure the time between two versions of code, after running it hundred times. The programm actual interrupts at a point. It is someone else's task to fix it. So what I already did is, I called the programm  from another script in a for loop. But after the occuring error (FileNotFoundError), I didn't find a way to return to the outest loop, yet, to let it run once again.

I already put before the point, where the error occurs, a try part, but I don't know what to put in the except part. Sure, I can put everywhere, in each used function, a "return" to end up in the outest loop. Is there a way much simplier than that?

```
with open('bla-program.py') as f:
    script = f.read()
    z = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
    a = time.time()

for i in z:
    exec(script)  ### now, that's the point, I cannot reach again

b=time.time()
print(a, b, "difference", b-a)
```

\now calling various functions, calculating some stuff, ... follows, landing in another file directed by bla-program, where error is occuring, is displayed below

```
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(bla.blabla, "bladibla.org"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    return  ###on this point, I want to return to the point displayed above
```

Instead of the termination of run by the FileNotFoundError, I want to run the program hundred times to the point of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `try/except` around `exec(script)`:

```
for i in z:
    try:
        exec(script)
    except:
        # Print an error message or whatever
```

Comment: I already did this, but it doesn't work, because the run is already terminated, it cannot return anymore

Comment: Do you have a call to `exit()` or `quit()` in the script? If not, `exec` should always return to the caller.

Comment: okay, i thought, i tried it already, but something went wrong.. i think now it works, thank you :D